# Why does the interrupt disable method to achieve mutual exclusion not work for multiprocessor systems?

Tags: operating-systems

The interrupt disable method to achieve mutual exclusion works for uniprocessor systems.
Why does the interrupt disable method to achieve mutual exclusion not work for multiprocessor systems?

Comment: I'm reading *Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces (OS:TEP)*, and this is a question I just had after reading the section on evaluating locks. Thus it's unclear to me why this question was downvoted.

Comment: Disabling interrupts does not prevent the processors from working and interfering with each other. In fact, disabling other processor's interrupts does not help at all, but may slow down their operation for no reason.

Answer (score 7):

Mutual exclusion means that during some time, a certain piece of code (called a critical section) has exclusive control over a resource. Interrupts can break that because they cause control to be transferred from critical section to the interrupt handler. Code running on other processors can break that because they can access the resource at the same time. Therefore, on a multiprocessor machine, disabling interrupts is not sufficient to achieve mutual exclusion. There also needs to be a way to prevent the other processors from accessing the resource.

Disabling interrupts is sufficient when it's the only way for the critical section to lose control. On a multiprocessor machine, the critical section does not have exclusive control in the first place.

Comment: Do you mean "mutual exclusion" instead of "multiple exclusion"? I haven't heard of the latter (at least yet).

Comment: @uzluisf Yes, I got my wires crossed between “multi processor” and “mutual exclusion”. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Np! Thanks for the answer :)